# I can't send Emails using Django non-rel on GAE

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, email, django-nonrel

Im trying to send a simple email to do the password recover of a user, the input is just a email to send the new password..

But i can't... i get this error

```
SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first
```

I already tried a few examples, like, https://bitbucket.org/andialbrecht/appengine_emailbackends/overview, but i get the same error

I really need this, maybe someone can tell me how to use an alternative to code in my view to send an email...Also i changed the backend to

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'djangoappengine.mail.EmailBackend'
```

but nothing,i don't know how to use this backend anyway :(

Plz Help :(

Answer (score 0):

> maybe someone can tell me how to use an alternative to code in my view to send an email...

I can help with this, seeing as it seems that perhaps this repository you're trying to use is based on an earlier version of App Engine and is throwing the error due to a required code change somewhere in the library - either that or the fact that you changed the string from what the library recommends (your version: 'djangoappengine.mail.EmailBackend') to a string that seems to not be correct, as it's different to what the author of the repository directed you to use (their version: 'appengine_emailbackend.EmailBackend'), and this is causing trouble.

Whenever possible, I'd recommend seeing if there is an "app-engine-y" way to do something, before going to a third-party library or deploying a module somebody else wrote to hack in third-party capabilities, or looking for an advanced/experimental feature (for example, use Datastore first, rather than remotely connecting to a MySQL VM, unless you *need* MySQL). If you absolutely *need* that library, this is a different story, but if you just want to send emails, the [Mail API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/#Python_Sending_mail_in_Python) is what you need. It's a convenient way to send emails on App Engine.

I'm going to assume in the following that you are storing your user's usernames and hashed passwords in custom-defined `User`-kind entities in your Datastore. If you have your users using simple OAuth to sign into your site, there is never any reason to "reset/recover password":

1. Create the `<form action="/some/route" action="POST">` element on
   the page where the user requests password recovery.
2. Put the code responsible for handling this form submission (they will input their email, or whatever account info they need for your code to find their `User` entity in the Datastore in a handler that will respond on that route.
3. In the handler, generate a unique token and store it in the Datastore. Send the token in the email that you generate and send using the Mail API (see the example code in the link to the docs I provided). This will allow your user to return to your site, authenticate with the token from the email, and then fill out a form to create a new password. You will then hash this password (with a salt) and store it in their `User` entity in your Datastore.

I'm skipping over the details of how to implement a "password recovery form", given what I said about OAuth and that you are probably really only concerned with how to send mail. In the email you send, for example, you can insert a hyperlink to your site with the token already inserted as a query param, so that the user doesn't have to copy and paste, etc.